# ngIf else with angular Ionic template

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, conditional-statements, ng-template

I'm trying to understand how the ngIf/else works, maybe it's something stupid but I don't get it.
Basically I need to print some content if my array is full (and this works fine) and some other content if is empty (which is not working).
This is my array which contains elements from a filtered json array.

```
public gbrumdatafiltered : Array<any> = [];
```

And this is the code.
As I said, when there are data in gbrumdatafiltered it prints "true", so the condition works, but if the array is empty (as per screenshot) nothing happens.

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let gbrumd of gbrumdatafiltered">
 <div *ngIf="gbrumd?.length; then gbrumdknown; else gbrumdunknown"></div>
  <ng-template #gbrumdknown>true</ng-template>
  <ng-template #gbrumdunknown>false</ng-template>
</ion-card>
```

I've tried even with some variations like:

```
    <div *ngIf="gbrumdatafiltered?.length; then gbrumdknown; else gbrumdunknown"></div>
--
    <div *ngIf="gbrumdatafiltered?.length; then gbrumdknown; else gbrumdunknown"></div>
--
    <div *ngIf="gbrumdatafiltered.length > 0; then gbrumdknown; else gbrumdunknown"></div>
```

But still doesn't works

This is the cconsole.log(this.gbrumdatafiltered); command

[image]

So, the array is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just have a logical error here, you need your conditional a bit higher up...

```
<ng-container*ngIf="gbrumdatafiltered?.length; then gbrumdknown; else gbrumdunknown">
</ng-container>
<ng-template #gbrumdknown>
 <ion-card *ngFor="let gbrumd of gbrumdatafiltered">
  <div>true</div>
 </ion-card>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #gbrumdunknown>
 <ion-card *ngIf="submitted">
  <div>false</div>
 </ion-card>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Thank You, in this way it works but it always prints the "false" condition.. I just forget to write in the post that I have even a submit button. I need to print one content if the input value is odd and another if it's even but just when the user input something.

Comment: this code prints the false condition if there are no items in the array or no array. not sure what you're after besides that

Comment: Basically I need to print only after the user submit a value. Nothing before

Comment: then you need some kind of variable indicating if a value was submitted and leverage it... added something to my answer to show what that MIGHT look like